# Use a Enum Bastetype as Key in a abstract Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, key

First I want to say that I am quite new to C# sharp. Is there any way implement a construct like the following? Or is there any other way to archive this?

```
public interface IClass 
{ 
    Dictionary<Enum, ISecondClass> { get; } 
}

public abstract class ClassBase : IClass
{
    public abstract Dictionary<Enum, ISecondClass> { get; protected set;}
}

public class ConcreteClass : ClassBase
{
    public override Dictionary<ConreteEnum, ISecondClass> { get; protected set;}
}
```

EDIT:
*I forgot to say that the concrete instance of the Dictionary needs to implement a custom Enum-comparer that need a concrete enum to get initialized*

**For all who are interested in the custom enum-comparer, which is needed in this case, take a look at this link: [Custom-Enum-Comparer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EnumComparer.aspx)**

Comment: Beware that using an enumeration as a dictionary key will box the enum type during comparisons as it doesn't implement IEquatable. See: http://beardseye.blogspot.com/2007/08/nuts-enum-conundrum.html

Comment: Thanks for that advice but I already know that and therefor instantiate the dictionary with a custom enum-comparer. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EnumComparer.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a generic type argument to the class/interface level

```
public interface IClass<TEnum>
{ 
    Dictionary<TEnum, ISecondClass> { get; } 
}

public abstract class ClassBase<TEnum> : IClass<TEnum>
{
    public abstract Dictionary<TEnum, ISecondClass> { get; protected set;}
}

public class ConcreteClass : ClassBase<ConcreteEnum>
{
    public override Dictionary<ConcreteEnum, ISecondClass> { get; protected set;}
}
```